# Don't know how to make this compile right: incompatible types in assignment

Tags: c++, arrays

sorry, I'm not a very advanced programmer, could you guys help me find a solution for this?

```
class Person
{
    private:
        char name[50];
        double age;
    public:
        void setName(char []);
        void setAge(int);
        char* getName();
        double getAge();
};

void Person::setAge(int a)
{
    Person::age = a;
}

char* Person::getName()
{
    return name;
}

double Person::getAge()
{
    return age;
}

void Person::setName(char n[])
{
    Person::name = n;
}
```

and it keeps giving me

```
"[Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [50]'"
```

I want to make this work *without* using an overloaded assignment operator, please help

Comment: Very easy: replace `char name[50]` with `std::string name;`. You need to `#include <string>` for that.

Comment: how can I do this without using string and just an array of characters?

Comment: In this case it might be obvious, but:
Line numbers in code and errors usually help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) (requires `n` to be '\0' terminated):

```
void Person::setName(char n[])
{
    strncpy(name, n, sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0]) - 1);
}
```

or make `name` an `std::string` then your original code will work. Also instead of writing `char n[]` its better to `const char* n` as `n` in your `setName` function is actually a pointer to first element. Also by making it `const` you allow to pass string literals to your function.

Comment: well I would use string, but our professor insisted on using an array of characters to make it "challenging" :|

Comment: The code also requires strlen(n) to be less than sizeof(name) to produce valid (zero-terminated) output.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did, thanks guys for answering, I appreciate it :D

```
char *name;

void Person::setName(char n)
{
    name = new char[n];
}
```

Comment: I hope your Person destructor contains the matching delete.
And you constructor does some sensible (nullptr) initialization ;)

Comment: And "new char[n]" ... WTF?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace char name[50]; with char *name and it will work just fine..